# Passing parameter value which includes context path in custom jsp tag via taglib

Tags: java, jsp, parameter-passing, jsp-tags, taglib

I have a custom JSP tag, via taglib, which takes a parameter. I need to modify the value passed to include the context path. Unfortunately, I got an HTTP 500 error when doing so.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/taglibrary.tld" prefix="custom" %>
<custom:redirect uri="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/foobar.jsp" />
```

Just passing the context path or the page itself works, but not the two together.

```
// Good
<custom:redirect uri="<%=request.getContextPath()%>" />
// Good
<custom:redirect uri="foobar.jsp" />

// Bad
<custom:redirect uri="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/foobar.jsp" />
// Bad
<custom:redirect uri="<%=request.getContextPath()%>" + "/foobar.jsp" />
```

How can I concatenate the two on-the-fly and set it the uri parameter? Or, is there no way other than to create a new string whose value is the context path and the page and then passing said string to the uri parameter?

FYI: I'm on Servlet 2.4. So, perhaps certain JSTL or EL operations may not be possible with this older version.

Thank you very much for any help.

**Update**

I was able to get it to work using scriplets:

```
<custom:redirect uri="<%=request.getContextPath() + \"/foobar.jsp\" %>" />
```

But we all know scriplets are bad practice. Not quite sure how to get it to work using straight EL.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't use a scriptlet to build the attribute of a tag. Use EL: `<custom:redirect uri="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/foobar.jsp" />`. Actually, you shouldn't be using scriptlets at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did try that but the contextpath did not resolve. It's literally passed as `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/foobar.jsp`.

Comment: Then you didn't define attribute `uri` as dynamic (`<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>`).